# Does BB10 support USB connection API?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

Does BB10 support USB connection API? On official BB site, I didn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. But they spoke about it In a blackberry jam, without specific release date i can remember.

Comment: Just an up: it's in the roadmap for August: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/download/roadmap/)/